# Expand the width of Dash dropdown options beyond parent Div

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I've built a dashboard using Dash (2.0.0) in Python and run into an issue. In my appp I have a side bar with several dropdown menus that needs to be narrow. Unfortunately, some of the dropdown option names are longer than what can fit in the sidebar. I'd like to have the dropdown options extend beyond the parent container when open, but I'd like the dropdown button itself to remain within the container. It's fine if the selected option appears truncated in the button, but I want the full options text visible when the dropdown is open.

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg6i5.png)

Dash Bootstrap Components dbc.Select() handles this perfectly, but unfortunately I need to use dcc.Dropdown(). Below is a simple example.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html

app = Dash(__name__)

dcc_dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
    options=[
        {'label': 'short name', 'value': 0},
        {'label': 'normal-length name', 'value': 1},
        {'label': 'annoyingly long and verbose name', 'value': 2},
    ],
    style={
        'white-space': 'nowrap',
        'text-overflow': 'ellipsis',
    },
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[dcc_dropdown],
    style={
        'width': '200px', # Div width is fixed
        }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Adding `style={'width': '300px'}` to dcc.Dropdown affects both the width of the dropdown options (desired) *and* the dropdown button itself (undesired), so the solution to the [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988494/adjust-width-of-dropdown-menu-option-in-dash-plotly) doesn't work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a solution that worked for me. Two things were needed to get the desired behavior:

1. One of the parent containers was set to `style={"overflow": "auto"}`. This needed to be removed.
2. I needed to manually set the width of the `Select-menu-outer` element. I didn't want to change all dropdowns so I created a custom class `wide-dropdown`:

```py
dcc.Dropdown(..., className="wide-dropdown")
```

And added the following to ./assets/custom.css :

```css
.wide-dropdown .Select-menu-outer {
  width: 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a callback that calculates a new width based on the value that is selected in the dropdown. Experiment with some much width you'd give each letter to your suiting. If you don't mind a bit of each space, then about 11-13px per letter will do the trick. Here's an example:

```py
app.layout = html.Div(
    id="div",
    children=[
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id="dropdown",
        options=[
            {'label': 'short name', 'value': 0},
            {'label': 'normal-length name', 'value': 1},
            {'label': 'annoyingly long and verbose name', 'value': 2},
        ],
    ),
    ])


def adjust_dropdown_width(value, options):
    print(value)
    width = (
        # default width if you erased the value
        "100px"
        if value is None
        # this assumes that each letter in the label is 11px wide, you can
        # change this to your preference
        else f"{len(options[value]['label'])*11}px"
    )
    return [{'width': width}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated my question clarifying the issue! I believe your solution would change the dropdown button width depending on the selected option. I'd like the button width to remain fixed at 200px but the dropdown "options" (only visible when when the menu is "open") to be >200px.